# Deploying PlayFramework Application to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, playframework

For my new project I am planning to use PlayFramework and Google App-Engine. I was trying to create a sample application in playframework and tried to deploy it to app-engine.

it says the application is deployed successfully, but when I hit the [url of my application](http://playdeamon.appspot.com/)

it shows a message "Your application is ready", But does not show the home page of my application.

I am using Play Framework 1.2 and GAE-1.4 plugin. I tried to deploy the application using the plugin and also using "appcfg".

The application works fine in local development mode but as soon as I deploy it to app-engine, the home page is replaced by "Your application is ready" message.

Can u guys tell me if I am doing anything wrong with the deployment of play-framework? I tried searching if anybody faced similar kind of issues in both google and SO but was not able to find any help.

Also, I read some post that GAE plugin does not work with Play-Framework 2.0(**Note : I am using Play 1.2 in the above example)** . I would like to know How can I deploy a play2.0 application in appengine.

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you add application name and version number in appengine-web.xml before deploy?